# Induction of representations of decomposition groups to Galois groups

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $G=Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$, and $D_\mathfrak{p} = \{\sigma \in G : \sigma(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{p}\}$ is the decomposition subgroup of $G$ corresponding to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$. If $\rho$ is a representation of $D_\mathfrak{p}$ over a field $F$, we can induce $\rho$ to get a representation of $G$.

Now given a representation of $G$ over $F$ how can we decide if it is induced from some decomposition subgroup? Can a $G$-representation be induced from decomposition subgroups for two or more different prime ideals of $K$ that lie above different rational primes? What is an example of a $G$-representation that is not induced from any of its decomposition subgroups? If these $G$-representations exist, do they have a name?

Comment: Away from the finitely many ramified primes the decomposition groups are the cyclic subgroups of $G$. Iff the image of $\rho$ is cyclic then $\rho$ is a subrepresentation of $Ind_{D(\mathfrak{p})}^G \rho$ for some (thus infinitely many) unramified primes.

Comment: $D(\mathfrak{p})$ is a [solvable group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group), so the 1-dimensional trivial representation of some non-solvable $G$ won't be equal to $Ind_{D(\mathfrak{p})}^G \rho$ for any prime.